# how to select the exactly wanted rows from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem in my sql.
I have 2 tables named `treatments` and `treatmentusers`. The `treatments` table has 2 fields named `id` and `treatment`. In `treatmentusers` I have 3 fields `id`, `userid`, and `treatmentid`. My need is to select all the fields from the `treatment` table along with the `userid` in `treatmentusers`. But there is a condition that 
   Selecting the rows only for a specific `userid`. (eg:`userid=1` only). If the `userid` `treatmentid` combination is not present in the `treatmentusers` table the cell value must be a `null` or 0.

Comment: An `INNER JOIN` would only retrieve rows with a match on the left and right-hand tables.

Comment: aleks i dont know why you down voted. May be you didnt understand my question. I know to write the join operation and i have the query too
   SELECT tbl_treatments.id,tbl_treatments.treatment,tbl_treatmentusers.userid FROM tbl_treatments LEFT JOIN tbl_treatmentusers ON tbl_treatmentusers.treatmentid=tbl_treatments.id .
This is not actually i am looking for. i need to find the rows with userid=1 or userid=null

Comment: If you include in your question what you've tried, what the result was, and exactly how your goals differ from that result, people will be a lot more able and willing to help you.

Comment: You are close.  Add "and userid=1" to your join condition.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk. i tried it too. but i couldn't get the rows from treatments which have not an entry in treatmentusers. i need to get those rows too with userid as null

Comment: can anybody help. please

Comment: why someone down voting this question without posting a right answer ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a left join and have the userId requirement as part of the ON clause.

```
SELECT t.*, tu.userid
FROM treatments t
LEFT JOIN treatmentUsers tu 
    ON t.Id = tu.treatmentId 
    AND tu.userId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.*, TU.userid FROM treatments T
  INNER JOIN treatmentusers TU ON T.userid = TU.userid
  WHERE TU.userid = '1';
```

If userid in treatmentusers table is number type then

```
.....WHERE TU.userid = 1;
```

Comment: this is not the solution :(